# what are these insects on my roses and how to kill them?

Tags: insects, roses

I woke up and saw these are on my roses, and they are on a some spider web-shape thing, maybe they're baby spiders, and they are moving on the flower and there are some things on the leaves that I think they're related to the babies, I also have used a systemic insecticide (imidacloprid) so they can't be sucking the flowers they're just living in them (the photos are taken behind a window so there's a bit of reflection in the glass.):
[image: things on the leaves]

that is the things on the leaves, I'm not sure they're related to this.

[image: baby spiders?]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was just about to say the same as Gardener J - probably spider mites, yes, and neem oil, yes, but first you could just try spraying with water frequently, on the tops and undersides of the leaves and all the stems - spider mites like hot and dry conditions and will absolutely not appreciate wet or damp leaves and stems, so this will help by making the environment less attractive for them. Neem is only a partial solution, and you need to be careful about how often you use imidaproclid and neem - don't use together, and don't use imidproclid unless necessary and not more often than is stated in the useage instructions.

Comment: Good thought on the misting idea, hadn't considered that. Would you think the dampness might encourage fungal development though? Roses aren't exactly known for resistance to leaf diseases.

Comment: Where the questioner lives is very hot and dry, so there's less risk - but it is a risk. Between one thing and another, roses aren't the greatest subjects for easy care...

Comment: Don't mist...use hard streams of water.  Get the old blooms OFF by cutting back to (an outside facing 5 leaflets leaf...ha).  Water only during the day so that the humidity is not high at night.  Clean up debris around the base of the rose that holds moisture and harbors insects/slugs.

Comment: Wait!!  I love spiders...they do so much of the work to keep other insect populations in balance.  Spider mites are so small that I have always had to use a loop to see them!!  The webbing on your rose look like REAL baby spiders!! Please cut those roses off and put where those babies can help your garden.  Are these plants indoors?  Green house?  Out of doors?

Comment: Remove baby spiders before spraying with Neem.  If you are in a green house you really want to keep these guys!  You do have spider mites and dust and yuck.  But you don't want to ruin whatever balance you've got going.  NEVER USE SYSTEMICS!!  That is sort of like using a nuclear bomb on New York to kill a few bad guys.

Answer (score 8):

They are not baby spiders, but you are not too far off target. They are Spider Mites. Spider mites drink the sap of plants and in great enough numbers they can cause severe damage. The webbing is also from them, they produce it in an attempt to protect themselves from predators and to shield themselves from unfavorable climate conditions. Spider mites are not insects, they are actually more closely related to spiders and scorpions (all three are Arachnids).

Your insecticide, imidacloprid, is specifically targeted to insects and has no direct impact on mites ([Source](http://www.walterreeves.com/tools-and-chemicals/imidacloprid-will-not-kill-spider-mites2/)). Many insecticides can actually make a spider mite infestation worse, because many of the spider mites natural predators are insects. If you spray to kill the insects you may remove beneficial insects that are trying to eat your mite infestation. If that weren't bad enough some insecticides, like [Carabyl](http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/PMG/PESTNOTES/pn7405.html) actually encourage mites to reproduce faster.

Spider mites strongly favor dry, hot conditions. Also they tend to show up the worst on plants that are already suffering from drought stress, which may or may not be relevant to your current situation. Neem oil, as well as several other kinds of insecticidal oils seem to be your best option. Make sure you get good coverage, as it only effects the mites it hits.

Comment: Am I wrong that spider mites are too difficult to see without magnification?  It looks like real baby spiders on that dead rose to me...what do you think?

Comment: Difficult perhaps, but not impossible.